# How to assimilate into visual studio code from visual studio ( the difference of hotkeys )?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have been using VS for years. I'm trying to use vscode to develop frontend project.

This is my first time touching visual studio code. I feel the hotkeys are so different when compared with visual studio 2015. For example, format code in VS is <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> and format code in visual studio 2015 is <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>alf</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>. If I even want to perform a simple copy/paste folder operation I also cannot.

As I know, visual studio code supports customized hotkeys. So, I think that someone may have already config the hotkeys in a form like visual studio 2015. 
However, I'm not sure this is even possible.

Please give me some suggestion or direction.

Comment: You're not sure what is even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to solve this:

1. manually recreating all the keys you love from Visual Studio in your keybindings.json
2. Hoping somebody else has made one that you can copy and paste into your keybindings.json -- I can't find any
3. Find one in the [marketplace.](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?term=keybindings&target=VSCode&sortBy=Relevance) There are a few keybinding extensions, but I don't see any for Visual Studio, though there is a Resharper one if you're used to that.

If you do end up doing number 1, you could benefit the community by bundling it as an extension to share on the marketplace.

**Edit:** typo. exceptions -> extensions